# SQLAlchemy disable cascade on a relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, cascade

In my database I have a view called `my_view`. I use the view to join it with another table `my_table`. Cause I don't now a way to map a view with the orm-mapper of SQLAlchemy, I mapped `my_view` like any other table. I give the primary-key in the relationship definition:

> some_value = relationship("MyView", primaryjoin=my_view_id == MyView.id, useList=False)

This for fine, until I try to delete from `my_table`. The error is:

> AssertionError: Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'my_view.id' on Instance '<MyView at 0x...>'

I am sure, the error happens, cause the mapper tries to delete a row from `my_view`. I found the `cascade` parameter, but I don't find out how I can stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relationship option: `passive_deletes="all"`

See https://docs-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.passive_deletes

> Additionally, setting the flag to the string value ‘all’ will disable
> the “nulling out” of the child foreign keys, when there is no delete
> or delete-orphan cascade enabled. This is typically used when a triggering
> or error raise scenario is in place on the database side.